# How to keep Sitecore.Social from complaining about Ninject?

Tags: configuration, social-connected

Sitecore Social loves to fill my logs with this:

```
Sitecore.Social: Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7 is not loaded. Couldn't determine the Social channels.
```

We're not using the module at all. Is there an easy way to disable it without breaking things (and without adding Ninject)?

Comment: I had a similar issue which I resolved by commenting out the line `<setting name="Social.IoC.AssemblyFullName" value="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7" />` in Sitecore.Social.config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sitecore.Social lives in \App_Config\Include\Social and is controlled by the various configs that live there.

If you do not want to use the module at all, you can completely disable it by doing the following:

1. Delete the Social folder.
2. Delete all Sitecore.Social.*.dll from \bin

I've tested this on Sitecore 8.1U3 and Sitecore 8.2.

Hope this helps!